# How to replace &nbsp; with a space?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php

I am creating some code to auto-generate a meta-desc for product pages in VM.

I have stripped tags, but I am still seeing `&nbsp` in the resulting text.

The code I have at present is:

```
if ($product->metadesc) {
    $document->setDescription($product->metadesc);
} else {
    $document->setDescription(strip_tags("Buy ".$category->category_name." | ".$product->product_name." | ".$product->product_desc));
}
```

So for example, this produces:

```
Buy T-Shirts | PTB Keep Calm | PTB Keep Calm This creative design is printed&nbsp;&nbsp;on a&nbsp;Premium Fitted CVC Crew Tee&nbsp; Features:60% combed rin...
```

Is there anything I can do to remove these non-breaking space entities?

Comment: Try `$document->setDescription(strip_tags(html_entity_decode("Buy ".$category->category_name." | ".$product->product_name." | ".$product->product_desc)));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php), as suggested by Lodder, is a suitable function call.  If you wish to "mop up" consecutive spaces, a simple, broad sweeping regex call will do the trick.

*I have added the unicode pattern modifier for maximum replacement coverage.

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/75l2o):

```
$category = new stdClass();
$category->category_name = 'T-Shirts';
$product = new stdClass();
$product->product_name = 'PTB Keep Calm';
$product->product_desc = 'PTB Keep Calm This creative design is printed&nbsp;&nbsp;on a&nbsp;Premium Fitted CVC Crew Tee&nbsp; Features:60% combed rin...';

$decoded = strip_tags(html_entity_decode("Buy " . $category->category_name." | ".$product->product_name." | ".$product->product_desc));
echo $decoded;

echo "\n---\n";

echo preg_replace('~\s+~u', ' ', $decoded);
```

Output:

```
Buy T-Shirts | PTB Keep Calm | PTB Keep Calm This creative design is printed  on a Premium Fitted CVC Crew Tee  Features:60% combed rin...
---
Buy T-Shirts | PTB Keep Calm | PTB Keep Calm This creative design is printed on a Premium Fitted CVC Crew Tee Features:60% combed rin...
```

---

Of course, if you don't have any other entities to decode and you want to condense spaces, you could just use regex.

```
echo preg_replace('~(?:\s|&nbsp;)+~u', ' ', strip_tags("Buy " . $category->category_name." | ".$product->product_name." | ".$product->product_desc));
```